# nginx + Let's Encrypt + reverse proxy = infinite redirect loop

Tags: nginx, redirect, nginx-reverse-proxy

Any idea why this Nginx config is causing infinite redirects?

```
  listen 80;
  server_name site.example.com;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name site.example.com;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

  access_log /var/log/nginx/site.example.com.log;
  location / {
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
     root /var/www/site.example.com/;
     allow all;
   }
}
```

This is a Digital Ocean droplet, and the purpose is to run Resilio Sync, which sits on 127.0.0.1:8888. When I try to access the site, it just gets redirected to https://site.example.com/ over and over again. As far as I can tell, the `return 301` in the first `server` block is the only thing here that would do a redirect, but I still get this problem even if I comment that line out.

I've pored through the multiple SO questions over the same topic, and none of the solutions seem to apply here. I'm not using CloudFlare. What am I doing wrong here? Everything worked earlier today, except the certificate had expired. The syncing still works fine, it's just the Nginx setup to access the web GUI that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Hah, of course I come up with the answer minutes after posting the question, after first banging my head on the wall for a long time...

This was in the Resilio Sync config file:

```
"webui" :
{
    "force_https": true,
    "listen" : "127.0.0.1:8888"
}
```

I set `force_https` to `false` and restarted `rslsync`, and then it works.